# Disable Google Contacts Preview

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Just today when I click on `Contacts` in Gmail, it opens a new tab with a new contacts web application.  **Please tell me how to disable this and get back to the old version of contacts (Gmail).**

It's funny that I was just trying to help my girlfriend last week, because she can no longer send me email easily because it always wants to send through a Google circle even if we directly enter the email. I was trying to fix it in that New app (that somehow she had a few weeks before me) and it was impossible. They really broke things this time.

Also found search doesn't work as well.  It can't even find the emails that it brings up as suggestions when composing an email and entering a name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<del>In the side menu click *More* → **Leave the Contacts preview** you will be taken to old Google contacts.</del>

Now the menu is *More* → **Switch to the old version**

[image]